# Dependent drop down list from three different database tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am new with AJAX and JQuery so I am finding difficulty with this. I currently have one dropdown box which is populated from a database. There are three values shown which are from three different database tables. The next dropdown box should depend on what is chosen from the previous dropdown. If one of the values are chosen, it should display ID's from that one particular table. This is my code so far:

HTML & PHP:

```
<div class="activity">
    <form action="" id="activity" name="activity" method="GET">
        <table class="table" id="activity"> 
        </br>
        <p><b> Create an Activity: </b></p>      
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="activity_name" id="activity_name" placeholder="Activity Name" class=""/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="activityTable">
        <tr id="copyRow">
            <td><input type="text" name="day" id="day" placeholder="Day" class=""/></td>
            <td>Activity Type: <?php
                $sql = "SELECT activity_type as activity_type FROM activity1 UNION SELECT activity_type as activity_type FROM activity2 UNION SELECT activity_type as activity_type FROM activity3";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                echo "<select name='activity_type'>";
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['activity_type'] ."'>" . $row['actitivy_type'] ."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>Activities(s): <select name="activities" size="2" multiple="multiple" style="width:70px">
                <option> </option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" id="deletebutton" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="addbutton">
    <input type="button" name="add" value="+" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" onclick="addRow('activity')">
</div>
</form>
<div class="button">
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
  var row = document.getElementById("copyRow"); // find row to copy
  var table = document.getElementById("activityTable"); // find table to append to
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
  table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}

function deleteRow(btn) {
    var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it should say $sql = "SELECT activity_type as activity_type FROM activity1
                UNION SELECT activity_type as activity_type FROM activity2
                UNION SELECT activity_type as activity_type FROM activity3";

Comment: small slightly off topic point: you can just do `select activity_type from activity1`. you only need the `as activity_type` clause if you want to change the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing jQuery *(though I don't see any being used in your code example)*, you would use `on()`:

```
<select class="dynamic" name="activity_type">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="one">Activity One</option>
    <option value="two">Activity Two</option>
    <option value="three">Activity Three</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('change','.dynamic',function(){
        var useData                     =   {};
        useData[$(this).attr('name')]   =   $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/processing_page.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: useData,
            success: function(response) {
                /*
                   Do whatever code you want here and drop it where ever.
                   You could choose to just have your php page generate the 
                   html and you just drop it somewhere:
                   $('#spot').html(response);
                   or just send/receive/parse JSON and generate the html
                   with javascript.
                */
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```